# Почему новички любят прикладывать код фотографиями?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, новые-участники

Большая часть вопросов поступает от новичков, которые иногда удивляют формулировками вопросов, методами, которыми они решают задачи и т.д. Но больше всего непонятно, почему они так любят прикладывать код фотографиями.

Говорят, в последний год эта проблема стоит острее чем раньше.

Посему **вопрос непосредственно к новичкам**: почему вы так любите прикладывать код фотографиями?

Comment: Потому что новички не читатели, а писатели, и правила сайта остаются нечитанными. Я бы вообще предложил запретить писать вопросы, пока не просмотрен раздел справки о задавании вопросов. Да, есть риск, что будут тупо пролистывать до конца, но...

Comment: @Harry, всегда можно подключить небольшой опросник по материалам справки, например. Тогда будет шанс, что информация дошла до новичков

Comment: Очень разумное решение :)

Comment: Кто умеет нажать Print Screen и прислать картинку - это, по нынешним временам, просто гении. А есть такие, которые фотографируют экран PC мобильником и посылают фотографию. Это уже просто новый биологический вид, который скоро нас всех успешно и заменит.

Comment: @AlexF, я тут не так давно, но мне такие не попадались. Может оно и к лучшему)

Comment: новички таки пошли давать ответы))))

Comment: Вот так: https://habr.com/ru/post/694898/

Answer (score 18):

На данный вопрос совершенно точно невозможно дать объективный ответ.
Да и сами новички Вам на него ничего внятного ответить не смогут.
Но я постараюсь рассказать то, что я понял по данному вопросу...

**Если вкратце:** это просто неопытность и непонимание.

**Чуть подробнее:**
Я пытаюсь общаться со многими и доносить до них правила и суть сообщества, но обратная связь, которую я получаю часто просто не укладывается в моей голове и совершенно точно не соответствует моим ожиданиям.

- Кому-то так проще
- кто-то считает что так лучше
- но большая часть просто вообще **никогда не задумывалась об этом**

Они идут по принципу наименьшего сопротивления и **поступают так как привыкли**.

---

И я могу предположить откуда взялись такие привычки:

На данный момент б**О**льшую часть всего общения современного человека в сети(а у многих не только в сети но и в жизни) занимают мессенджеры.

И большинство вопросов, связанных с программированием, которые ко мне приходят в мессенджер - приходят именно в виде скриншотов ибо в мессенджерах ширина сообщения ограничена - форматирование теряется, а подсветка отсутствует.
Обмениватся кодом в мессенджере неудобно, поэтому большинство просто делают скриншот и скидывают его.

*пример типичного вопроса связанного с программированием **ВНЕ рамок stackoverflow:***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И прежде чем задавать вопрос на stackoverflow, многие пользователи получают опыт обмена информацией вне рамок ресурса, специально предназначенного для этого где и привыкают скидывать все в виде скриншотов.

Поэтому когда они задают вопросы и при этом, прикладывают код в виде скриншотов -
**они просто действуют по привычке, которая сформировалась вне ресурса или сообщества**, связанного с обменом опыта в области программирования, в котором бы они могли бы почерпнуть практики, которые лучше подходят для обмена той или иной информацией.

Comment: Очень хороший, полный, развернутый ответ, спасибо. Однако по идее @АлексейШиманский, которую он предложил в вопросе, который я упомянул выше, я создал этот вопрос, чтобы можно было отсылать сюда новичков, которые и прикладывают ответы фотографиями. Может и обратная связь соберется заодно)

Comment: @rusgeli, да, конечно. Я просто постарался описать свой опыт и свое понимание данного вопроса.

Comment: @rusgeli, мне кажется, что ощущение Алексея относительно того, что эта проблема приобрела какие-то новые масштабы последний год может быть как-то связано с тем, что Алексей долгое время отсутствовал на сайте.(не камень в огород... я про то, что он просто отвык) Меня же скриншоты и год назад, и два(и более) доставали...

Comment: плюс количество вопросов растет, а количество отвечающих падает, что увеличивает нагрузку на одного активного участника, публикующего ответы.

Comment: Кстати не согласен по поводу мессенджеров. Состоял в обществе пыхеров довольно большИм в телеге, там **всегда** просят кидать код на pastebin или песочниwe и прикладывать ссылку на него, а скрины в канале отключены специально....

Comment: "Кому-то так проще
кто-то считает что так лучше" --- вот и интересно "чем проще" и "почему лучше". Но это надо других слушать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, относительно сообществ в телеге... это также является специализированной площадкой ( к концу вопроса я свел к тому, что опыт формируется не в рамках специализированных сообществ. Возможно стоит это как-то выделить ) ... тем более что там специально отключены скрины

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, `вот и интересно "чем проще" и "почему лучше". Но это надо других слушать` - из моего опыта, это просто ничем не обоснованные заблуждения. Им просто так кажется, потому что по другому они раньше и не пробовали.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский + ко всему pastebin и различные песочницы также являются специализированными площадками и больщинство новичков либо не знают о них, либо не имеют опыта и привычки ими пользоваться.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне более чем понятно мотивация. "чем проще и лучше". Человек, который так делает просто перекладывает ответственность за решение задачи на более "опытного" и забывает. Потому что, когда его спросят о решении, он четко сможет ответить, что сделал все возможное. А то, как он это сделал, это уже другой вопрос и тут можно и дурачком прикинуться. Видал я такое много раз

Comment: @Dmitry, то что безответственность также может являться причиной такого поведения - согласен. Но не согласен, что это касается всех подобных случаев (`чем проще и лучше`). Подобные персонажи встречаются безусловно, но они как правило не дают обратной связи и не пытаются улучшить вопрос. Те же, что давали обратную связь  (`проще и лучше`) благодарили за разъяснения, шли навстречу и улучшали вопрос .Хотя многие из них - не сразу (это я для себя объясняю тем, что они просто попали в неизвестную среду, в которой пытаются освоиться...и на это нужно какое-то время).

Comment: @МихаилРебров бесспорно, кто нацелен на поиск решения, сделает все для этого. Мое отношение крайне позитивное и я стараюсь накидать положительных оценок и как то поддержать в комментариях, хотя вопрос может быть так себе. Кто ищет отмазку сделает все и для этого и вот тут я готов даже ответы минусить за поддержание и распространения лоботрясничества и конкретного неуважения к труду других людей

Comment: @Dmitry, да, я уже как-то предлагал в чате добавить новую причину для закрытия вопроса, как `"Отказ от помощи сообщества"` и описанное выше поведение идёт в ту же копилку.

Comment: Еще меня убивает когда люди задают вопрос, после чего либо целиком и полностью игнорируют уточняющие и наводящие вопросы в комментариях, либо отвечают на них спустя неделю или две...

Comment: @МихаилРебров каждая новая причина для закрытия - возможность ее использования. Возможно, лучше искать решения для донесения полезной информации до пользователей. Запрещать - это конечно у нас в крови, но по мне так лучше разрешать с оговорками. Конкретно здесь в этом случае, мои романтические мысли, добавить функционал для распознования текста с картинок и предлагать подправить перед публикацией вопроса. Но.... я не хочу это реализовывать, я тоже ленивый

Comment: @Dmitry `каждая новая причина для закрытия - возможность ее использования` - согласен. Я в принципе хотел как-нибудь обсудить то, что некоторые очереди проверок вынуждают закрывать вопросы чаще чем того хотелось бы... и тут вопрос больше не в количестве причин закрытия, сколько в том, что в некоторых очередях у тебя просто нет альтернатив. Вопрос либо однозначно хороший, либо однозначно плохой и тебе приходится выбирать... В очередях первых сообщений ситуация стала лучше после того как ввели возможность просто оставить отзыв в качестве результата аудита. Но вот в других очередях такого нет.

Comment: @Dmitry, в моем случае я говорил про такую причину закрытия, ссылаясь на совершенно запущенные случаи. Я в первую очередь пишу комментариии, прежде чем голосовать за закрытие или ставить минусы.

Comment: @Dmitry, в результате OCR будет много мусора из интерфейса IDE-шки.. разве что в виде как какого-то плагина на `stackapps`

Answer (score 16):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень просто, надо обратить внимание на подсказу справа, там есть и как код вставить и общие правила форматирования. Читать ленятся) А нажав, на кнопочку "Код" в редакторе, можно получить исчерапывающую информацию прям здесь, не отходя от дела

Comment: 'Неистово плюсую' за "приложу ответ фотографией"!

Comment: @Dmitry отсюда делаем вывод, что "3) Они не хотят понимать (читаем как "разбираться"), как прикрепить красиво" ))

Comment: Ответ на вопрос, в стиле вопроса - это self-descriptive - литературный способ, который намекает на высокий литературный (именно литературный, не программерский) профессионализм автора. Браво автор!

Answer (score 6):

Не буду гадать, почему алкающие ответов неофиты вставляют код скриншотами. Выдвину предложение.

Давайте добавим в окошко с инструкцией для первого вопроса чётко сформулированный посыл -- НИКАКИХ СКРИНШОТОВ!
[image: злобный месседж]

Не настаиваю на формулировке. Но раз скриншоты мешают сообществу, об этом стоить заявить прямо с порога.

Как-то так.

Answer (score 5):

Большинство людей сейчас пользуется телефонами. А компьютеров многие зачастую вообще не имеют, не только настольных, но и ноутбуков.
Соответственно, привыкли к тем способам ввода и передачи информации, которые удобнее и проще на смартфонах. Отсюда и скрины.
Конечно, осваивающие программирование пользуются компьютерами, потому что даже на смартфоне это почти невозможно. Но привычки-то остались.

Мне встречалось информация, что многие активные пользователи интернета, соцсетей, телеги и т. п., не умеют пользоваться файловой системой, не знают, что такое путь к папке/файлу. Потому что для использования мобилы это не нужно.
И среди джунов немало таких.

Comment: Есть тут один пользователь и в силу возраста он программирует на телефоне, поскольку родители не задумались купить ему машину, ну или другие обстоятельства. Такое тоже немного обескураживает

Comment: Вот этот пользователь [Пушистик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/494483/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba), 12 лет.

Comment: @Dmitry , Ну, ничего страшного. Я в своем детстве в тетрадке в клеточку программировал. Главное желание:-)

Comment: @МихаилРебров мне больше повезло, да и отец любитель электроники. С самых пеленок была у меня сначала самопальная машина (я даже не знаю что там было внутри, все в клавиатуре было и отец сам все это дело доставал/паял), а потом ZX Spectrum и по нарастающей)

Comment: @Dmitry, первого клона спектрума я увидел(не заимел) уже в сознательном возрасте и с вышеописанными тетрадями) если бы знал про существование подобного, то возможно заимел бы раньше

Answer (score 5):

Добавлю еще один ответ.

я не очень понимаю, почему об этом факте никто не упомянул, хотя выше написаны весьма развернутые ответы.

Для того, чтобы вставить код в вопрос, и вообще, **воспользоваться** *возможностями* ***форматирования*** на этом сайте - надо хотя бы немного изучить редактор.

Да, для тех, кто здесь пишет каждый день, редактор - это как дыхание. Ты уже не задумываешься, нажимая все эти прекрасные кнопочки для форматирования. Но все таки - это инструмент, и на его освоение нужно потратить время и внимание.

(также, передаю привет лор.ру, у которого вообще формтирование в вопросах делается в лучших линуксовых традициях - маркдауном, и через этот ***ад*** не может продраться ни один нормальный человек)

Ну так вот, новички увидели этот инструмент первый раз в жизни. Поэтому я иногда вижу, что и картинку с кодом не сразу удаётся в вопрос вставить.

Comment: Согласен. Сам постоянно правлю  форматирование вопросов и исправляю ошибки (неправильно вставленные фото и строки, которые были съедены тегами), но почему-то во время написания ответа об этом не задумался.

Comment: а я люблю маркдаун и по мне бы полностью бы на это дело перейти. Проблем поправить за новыми пользователями тоже не вижу, где-то даже в Справке было, что если не получается форматировать вопрос, мы поправим.

Comment: "у которого вообще формтирование в вопросах делается в лучших линуксовых традициях - маркдауном"  --- но ведь тут тоже в редакторе маркдаун -_-

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - здесь сверху, над полем ввода текста, есть кнопки, нажимая которые можно вставить в текст любое форматирование. А я критиковал подход, когда таких кнопок нет, и не знаешь синтаксиса- все, иди, гуляй...

Comment: @S.H. а, понятно, просто эти кнопки - помогают, но в целом весь синтаксис тут - маркдаун)) понятно

Comment: Хе-хе, да я просто дэмон из прэисподнэй! Атт мой дом! Я пишу исключительно в маркдауне :) Кнопку нажымаю только для загрузки картынок. Даже ссылки вставляю как `[]()`, без кнопкы.

Comment: @PakUula: Тогда уж пышу а не пишу. Так задушевней получается.

Answer (score 5):

К сожалению все куда проще))
Нас просто не покидает чувство что никто не будет досконально копаться в нашем говнокоде, так что мы автоматически пытаемся скинуть сразу суть, чтобы не отнимать много времени и не показаться навязчивыми, а сделать это проще фотографиями)))

Comment: И получается как раз в духе "хотели как лучше, а получилось как всегда". Еще очень раздражают вопросы, где фрагмент кода сопровождается диагностикой "не работает". Все. Понимай, как хочешь... Спрашиваешь подробности — "**этот** код не работает" (как будто тут есть другой)...

Comment: Тогда логичный вопрос: зачем приходить на ресурс и что-то спрашивать, если считаете, что до вас нет дела ("никто не будет досконально копаться в нашем говнокоде ")? Какой-то оксюморон, чесслово

Comment: Чем больше ты растешь в данной сфере, тем больше ты встречаешь "говнокода". Но это путь каждого и каждый пишет сначала плохо, не соблюдают паттерны, игнорируют лучшие практики и так далее. Но для этого и существует такая процедура как "code review", которая полезна обеим сторонам, и кто проверят и кого проверяют. Большинство отвечающих с одного взгляда понимают, что не так в коде, поэтому это чувство мне кажется не рациональным. Вот только как донести эту мысль до новичков не понятно

Answer (score 3):

Я как новичок, могу еще добавить, что действительно не хватает опыта в этом деле.

Не все понимают ценность грамотно сформулированного вопроса, потому что они никогда не были под другую сторону (в роли отвечающих) или очень мало на ней были.

У меня лично довольно богатый опыт вопросов-ответов в другой сфере, и когда ты всем новым людям объясняешь *правила игры*, понимаешь, что каждый новый человек вообще не задается вопросом:

> а как мне задать вопрос, чтобы получить эффективный ответ?

Я для себя сделал такой вывод:
У кого-то в течении жизни просто не произошло момента заставляющего впредь думать о качестве вопросов и пока как говорится "петух не клюнет", ничего не изменится у него голове.

Comment: Согласен, но хочу добавить, что необходимость - лучший учитель... Просто начиная с первого вопроса на этом ресурсе я был очень заинтересован в ответе, и потратил много времени, чтобы сразу правильно вопрос задать.

Answer (score 1):

Мое скромное мнение:

- Не все знают о возможностях редактора. Если основные иконки ("**B**", "*I*" списки, undo/redo) еще как-то интуитивно понятны (ибо такие же как в ЛЮБОМ редакторе - кстати, иконка жирного шрифта тут почему-то не жирная, хехе), то все остальные требуют изучения, ибо либо неочевидны, либо нелогичны. Например, иконки "пример кода" и "фрагмент кода" - вот кто подскажет новичку, чем они отличаются? А в незнакомое большинство новичков по умолчанию не лезет.
- Не все знают специфическую терминологию. Меня, например, в начале пребывания тут несколько раз макали в говния требованием "код надо вставлять в сниппет", но хоть один апостол текстового кода удосужился подсказать что это за хрень? Максимум пошлют в хелп, но, пардон, если б хоть один макатель сам там хоть раз в жизни побывал, он бы увидел, что там НИ СЛОВА о загадочных "сниппетах" нет.
- Наконец, не все догадываются, что код лучше давать текстом потому, что могут думать, что местные корифеи способны определить ошибку, прочитав и проанализировав код в уме. Это, конечно, лестно, но большая часть отвечающих все-таки нуждается в возможности скопировать и запустить код.
- Фраза "читай правила" - это жупел. Законники, вспомните себя и честно ответьте - когда вы в принципе читаете правила? Уверен, что не раньше, чем пытаетесь выяснить, за что вам сделали замечание или дали бан... И это не только к SO относится.

Новичкам надо помогать. Ну не все в принципе догадаются, что надо залезть туда-то или попробовать то-то. У большинства из нас, например, стоит MS Word - ну-ка, кто из нас пользуется всеми его возможностями? То-то, 90% отступы пробелами делают же ;)

Предлагаю запилить какую-нибудь страничку или пост с кратким и емким хелпом, и вынести линку на нее куда-нибудь, чтобы не рыться в недрах официальной документации, что ли...

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже новичок, не думала, что это могло быть проблемой... Я стараюсь либо "пихать" скриншоты **всего** (рил всего), либо вообще не вставлять их. Все же я обучаюсь и потихоньку вставляю код вместо скринов. Это нужно сказать всем новичкам про скрины с кодом хаха :)

Answer (score 0):

Друзья, по-моему всё еще куда проще, на stackoverflow нет нумерации строчек кода, нежели это есть в IDE.

Comment: обычно нумерация строк кода совсем не важна, как правило. Из ошибок ясно-понятно откуда растут ноги. Но это также мое видение, которое совсем не обязательное

Comment: Ну для того, чтобы скопировать код из редактора к себе в IDE или в песочницу и поиграться - нумерация в самом сниппете не нужна. .......... если код небольшой (условно строк 50) - тоже, а если код строк в 100-200-300 - то это вообще не по адресу ruSO вопрос..........опять же, если нужна нумерация  - можно скопировать код себе хотя бы в блокнот.... а скопировать тёмную фотку себе при  свете солнца - такое себе))