# Сообщество слишком агрессивно отмодерировало вопрос новичка

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

*Разбираем один конкретный вопрос, а не среднюю температуру по больнице.*

[Как сократить большие числа в Unity?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1555238/373567)

*UPD: Текст ниже потерял актуальность, так как относится к состоянию того вопроса до закрытия как дубликата. На момент написания сообщения дубль не был найден.*

Наминусились, что заблокировали человеку возможность задавать вопросы (навсегда, ну или пока баланс отрицательных или положительных голосов не восстановится). Оно реально того стоило?

- Кому реально "непонятна суть вопроса"?
- Кому кажется, что с тегом [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) это учебное задание?
- Кто-то требует код приложить в предлагаемой причине закрытия?

Вопрос точно все минусовавшие и проголосовавшие за закрытие читали?

И даже после того как вопрос отвечен, продолжают минусить и голосовать за закрытие. Я понимаю, что качество оформления вопроса оставляет желать лучшего. Но суть его проста и понятна. И это уж точно не учебное задание.

Это типичная проблема изучения Unity по ютубу, когда автор не зная языка пытается игры писать. Пришёл за помощью к нам. Почему так реагируем?

*Я хочу напомнить сообществу, что у нас приветствуются вопросы любой сложности, в том числе уровня такой элементарщины.*

---

UPD: Отредактировал заголовок того вопроса на более понятный.

Comment: Наверное, задача кажется обществу слишком элементарной. И поиском безотносительно юнити если поискать, тут же полно было ответов, как преобразовать цифры в "человеческие" типа килобайтов и т.п. Так что понять почему минусуют, наверное, можно. Хотя я лично такое не минусую. Действительно пришёл новичок, задание это или нет непонятно, может для себя человек разбирается.

Comment: @CrazyElf все так, есть такой ответ у меня https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1246708/373567, но разве он подходит по контексту? Хотя-бы если уровень знаний автора взять во внимание?

Comment: Да я в общем с вами согласен. Хорошо бы можно было видеть, кто всё-таки минусует вопрос и спросить их по-человечески, за что )  А ещё лучше, если бы при минусовании нужно было выбрать причину, как при голосах за закрытие, и можно было увидеть, по какой причине вопрос (да и ответ тоже, например) минусуют.

Comment: А может стоит это решить радикально и навсегда? Я имею в виду, что просто не надо блочить ни при каком соотношении голосов.  Можно ограничить количество вопросов в день, но навсегда блочить точно не надо

Comment: @avp голоса сообщества решают, блочить или нет. Наминусили вопросов - заблочили вопросы, наминусили ответов - заблочили ответы. Это автоматика, модератор не может снять или наложить такую блокировку.

Comment: @aepot он попал в бан по вопросам? Серьёзно? У него 2 вопроса: 1 с ответом и рейтингом -1, второй дубль, +3/-6. Маловато на блокировку.

Comment: @Зонтик три, ещё один дубль -3 удалённый им самим.

Comment: @aepot ну всё равно маловато, как мне кажется. Вот если ещё один такой же задаст, то точно попадёт.

Comment: @Зонтик уже не задаст.

Comment: @aepot, а поменять правила автоматики?

Comment: @avp правила нормальные, они зачастую работают как надо. Голоса - нет, не все.

Comment: @aepot, может с другими правилами все было бы иначе? Например, уровень контингента стал бы повыше, глядишь и не минусили бы без нужды. А вообще, тут давно уже сильные люди не приживаются ...

Comment: @aepot ну если вам его так жалко, то поставьте плюсики на все его вопросы, авось выйдет из блокировки. Но по-моему он создаст ещё одну учётку и будет с неё однострочники задавать.

Comment: @Зонтик то есть провоциррвать на создание учеток вместо того чтобы помогать авторам с оформлением вопросов - это нормально? Ну ок. Из блокировки в текущей ситуации он уже не выйдет.

Comment: @aepot просто блокировка, которую нельзя снять — это маразм. Она лишь провоцирует к созданию учёток. А люди вольны распоряжаться голосами, как им хочется.

Comment: @Зонтик отрицательные голоса накладывают баны на вопросы или ответы новичка, так было всегда. Это нормально. Полно ГПТшников таким образом перебанили. И удаление вопросов и ответов от этого не спасает, из бана не выйти.

Comment: @aepot ненормально то, что это снять НИКТО не может. И рекомендаций дельных НЕТ, как это сделать. Например, что сделать этому товарищу? У него 2 дубля, которые уже никак не улучшить. Писать ответы ему — не вариант (небольшой уровень знаний + стиль письма сообщений). Улучшить третий вопрос? Ну не получит же он вдруг кучу голосов, да так, чтобы из бана хватило выйти.

Comment: @Зонтик есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans

Comment: @aepot для большинства забаненых они не подходят. Как для этого, например.

Comment: Кажется, комментариев много стало... Grundy уже в пути.

Comment: Надо сделать функционал чтобы человек который минусует описывал почему он минусовал. А то многие даже вопрос толком не читают, видят минусы и сразу чтобы просто п.о.д.о.с.р.ть человеку минусуют.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ При этом я бы кроме отображения причины минусования еще добавил возможность указать причины плюсования. А меню закрытия вопроса по сути не нужно. Разве что только пункты для указания дубликата или переноса, как часть инструментов модераторов.

Comment: @MadokaMagica, такие предложения про "добавления причины минусования" каждый год раз по десят вносят. И каждый раз отклоняют.

Comment: @Глеб Ага, и каждый год читающие и, в первую очередь, задающие вопрос негодуют в непонятках, отчего вопрос хватает минусы.

Comment: @user7860670 Ты вот скажи а почему есть такая вещь как презумпция невиновности, почему человек считается невиновным пока не докажут обратное? Я думаю потому что человеку будет неприятно если он действительно не виноват а его уже считают преступником. Так же и тут, тыкнуть минус легко, но есть ли у тебя действ причина, если да то просто опиши ее, потому что возможно ты просто хочешь под.н.сать другому не задумываясь и боюсь это самая распространённая причина минусования в stackowerflow

Comment: @user7860670 что касается причины как я считаю не ставить причины + это то что я думал что стаковерфлов существует чтобы людям помогать и если даже этот + поставлен по ошибке плохо человеку от этого не будет. Но если человек мучается с проблемой уже дня два пишет в стаковерфлов за помощью и ладно помощи не получает, так еще и кучу минусов получает, потому что то не так написал. Ну так напишите что не так, не накидают просто -

Comment: @MadokaMagica, я лично сам первым поставил минус на этот вопрос. И я вовсе не хотел... как это п...ь   другому. Мне показалось, что вопрос как-то немного попахивает учебностью. Да и опечаток было много. Минусы для того и существуют, чтобы показать, что что-то в вопросе не то. На совсем плохие вопросы ставят 10 минусов, на немного плохие — 3. По количеству минусов автор может удобно судить о том что в вопросе не то. Вот и все.

Comment: @Глеб то то и оно а что не то? Автор не поймет что не то. Никто ж ему не напишет, потому что лень, а тыкнуть не лень. К тому же - ставить за опечатки и "учебность" ну это уже свинство. Там вроде за дубликат  закрыли, но кто ж проверял, по принципу минусовал че-то не понравилось.

Comment: К чему вообще эта мантра, что минусовавшие не читали вопрос? Смешно ведь, вопрос из одного предложения, что тут читать... Это вы не читали подпись под кнопкой минуса похоже, ибо вопрос абсолютно под нее подходит.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight нет, не подходит, в том то и дело. Додумывание о том, что автор поленился погуглить прежде чем задать вопрос в принципе противоречит общему отношению к вопросам на SO. Другими словами, формулировка под кнопкой опирается на чисто субъективное восприятие голосующего. В этом нет проблемы, когда речь не о новичках, так как баланс голосов в итоге выровняет ситуацию. Так мы баним за примитивные вопросы, или нет? Исходя из вашего комментария - да.

Comment: Лично я против подобных, базовых, вопросов на SO, ибо они из разряда "как кушать?", любой человек, получивший минимальные знания по данному языку, без проблем решит это. А это значит лишь одно, человеку нужно готовое, он плевать хотел на то, как это устроено, и с огромной долью вероятности он придет в следующий раз и задаст опять "как кушать?", захламляя тем самым сайт. НО Я не против человека, хочет так познавать язык, его право, банить за такое это бред, и огромный косяк SO (раз банит за 1 вопрос), который надо исправлять. Так что, если ценить вопрос, то минусы справедливы (моего там нет).

Comment: А вообще, тут проблема в том, что для многих SO = Форум, они не думают о ценности своих вопросов, они думают что тут быстро написали как на форуме, получили комменты, авось в их потоке найдется полезное. Вот если объяснить человеку что это не так, что SO это всеж некая база, то в следующий раз подумает, стоит задавать подобное или нет (было такое несколько раз, люди после упоминания начинали поступать иначе, либо просто уходили).

Comment: Дожили, модератор жалуется на сообщество, что сообщество слишком агрессивно модерирует.

Comment: P.S. с другой стороны - все же лучше так, чем молча переоткрыл/перезакрыл без пояснений

Comment: О, блокировку с автора сняли. Спасибо всем!

Comment: @aepot блокировку-то сняли, но надолго ли? Ещё один такой вопрос - и снова в бан улетит.

Comment: @Зонтик меня интересует дальнейшая судьба автора не больше, чем судьба любого другого участника. Речь шла о вопросе и блокировке за вопрос, а не об авторе.

Comment: Честно говоря, в шоке, что моя простая невнимательность породила такое обсуждение :)

Answer (score 6):

> Сообщество слишком агрессивно отмодерировало вопрос новичка

Давайте посмотрим, что с ним происходило и как его модерировали (для этого зайдём в [историю действий над ним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1555238/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)).

1. **Вопрос задан**. Первая его версия:

> ## Как убрать большие цифры в юнити?
>
> Никак не могу придумать, как сделать так, что-бы при достижении игроком 1000 очков, писало не 1000, а 1к и так же с миллионом, вместо 1.000.000 - 1М
> [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) [разработка-игр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80)

Что мы видим?

- Заголовок так себе и не отражает суть проблемы полностью.
- Есть пунктуационные ошибки (что-бы пишется слитно, в середине предложения вместо тире используется дефис, в конце нет точки).
- А вот метки расставлены хорошо (**UPD:** кто-то считает, что плохо. Но в таком случае качество вопроса ещё ниже, так что такое мнение подтверждает мою общую позицию ещё больше): есть и основные ([c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) и [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)), поставлена дополнительная [разработка-игр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80).
- Если произвести поиск, то выяснится, что такой вопрос [уже был задан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012943/532877).

Вывод: автор не читал статью [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), хотя новым участникам сейчас, как только они открывают страницу создания вопроса, показывается окно "Вы сейчас задаёте свой первый вопрос" с парой советов и ссылкой на эту статью (См. [скрин из этого ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12193/532877)). По крайней мере у меня это высвечивалось, когда я свой первый вопрос писал. Кроме того, вопрос однострочный, плюсом очень простой (оператор if решает проблему). Поэтому он и получает минусы:

> Вопрос **не отражает стремления разобраться**; он непонятен или **не несёт пользы**.

2. **Сообщение [попало в очередь "первые вопросы"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/894441)**. И никакого "агрессивного модерирования" он не получил: проверяющий вообще выбрал <kbd>Выглядит нормально</kbd>.
3. **Стали появляться комментарии**, подталкивающие автора к решению:

- > можно с помощью оператора if и деления
- > я бы посоветовал `Humanizer`, но не знаю ставится ли он на юнити

4. **Стали появляться минусы**. Начинается модерирование, о котором вы говорили. Но на "агрессивное" оно не тянет.
5. **Вопрос попал в очередь ["сообщения низкого качества"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/894445)**. в очереди результат такой: 3 "закрыть" против 2 "выглядит нормально". Я видел его в очереди. Но нажал <kbd>Пропустить</kbd>, так как не захотелось спасать очередной однострочник, но и "убивать" его тоже не было желание, потому что не за что. Думал минус поставить, но не поставил: возможно, вопрос сложнее, чем мне казался (т.к я не разбираюсь в его теме, может там какие-то подводные камни есть). Дубль тоже не стал искать. Потому что вопрос не по моей тематике, хотя оказалось, что есть дубль совсем очевидный.

   На самом деле закрывать его глупо, [уже много раз обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/532877). Суть вопроса ясна, mcve не нужен, ну и это явно не домашка. Тут нужна улучшающая правка. И всё.
6. Пришли добрые люди: дали [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1555246/532877), поставили плюсики сейчас у вопроса по голосам +3/-4 (**UPD**: после этого вопрос снова заминусовали в подвал до -3... -4, а потом заплюсовали обратно, на 11 ноября 2023 года 21 века второго тысячелетия нашей эры у вопроса рейтинг 0, 5 плюсов и 5 минусов).
7. Вопрос был отредактирован: сначала автор ответа [причесал заголовок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1555238/2), потом я [исправил пунктуацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1555238/3).
8. Вопрос закрыли как дубль, и вполне себе верно закрыли.

Вывод:

> Проблема раздута. Нельзя сказать, что модерирование было "агрессивным". Да, низкокачественные однострочники привлекают минусы и голоса за закрытие, но в этом (в большинстве случаев) виноваты их авторы, которые ни заголовок придумать нормальный не могут, ни текст на пунктуацию проверить (хотя для этого куча инструментов существует), ни сами разобраться не хотят.
>  Неужели оператор if такая сложная штука, что догадаться нельзя? Или загуглить и получить ответ тут же, а не задавать вопрос и ждать, пока дублем закроют?

Comment: Я и так видел, что с вопросом происходило. Но минусы то за что? За пунктуацию, серьёзно? Мне кажется, что не за это. Ладно, я уже понял, из бана автор вопроса уже не выйдет никогда. Штош.

Comment: @aepot нет, не только за пунктуацию. "Вопрос не отражает стремление разобраться; он не несёт пользы".

Comment: Что значит не несёт пользы?

Comment: @aepot он слишком прост и его можно нагуглить за секунду. При чём на том же сайте, на котором он и был задан.

Comment: Тогда нужно было задубликатить? Или ссылку дать на оригинал нагуглив за секунду? Никто из голосовавших этого не сделал.

Comment: @Зонтик "не несёт пользы" - на сайте полно вопросов, которые никогда не будут загуглены другими людьми и которые нужны только самому автору. По типу "помогите, олимпиадный код не работает" или "улучшите код". Ответами на такие вопросы опытные участники стабильно зарабатывают пару лайков и галочку. Но, что самое интересное, часто лайками удостаиваются даже и сами такие вопросы. Я на самом деле давно заметил, что определение качества и полезности вопросов сообществом зависит от настроения и прочих рандомных факторов, и редко бывает объективным. Не считая отношения к совсем неадекватным вопросам.

Comment: @aepot вообще-то его 5 человек закрыли как дубль.

Comment: @Byb такие вопросы несут пользу хотя бы автору + в теории, некоторые рекомендации по [tag:инспекция-кода] могут нести пользу другим.

Comment: Закрыл как дубль его только последний. Остальные голосовали не за дубль.

Comment: @aepot значит они не пытались искать дубль, но они и не должны по идее это были делать, вопрос не их и не по их меткам, видимо. Но голосовали за закрытие как домашку зря, да.

Comment: Там по сути все причины кроме дубля не подходят к этому вопросу.

Comment: @aepot я об этом писал: *"На самом деле закрывать его глупо, уже много раз обсуждали. Суть вопроса ясна, mcve не нужен, ну и это явно не домашка. Тут нужна улучшающая правка. И всё."* __P.S__ речь идёт о закрытие другими причинами, не дублем.

Comment: Какие то раздутые причины. Пунктуационные ошибки, че серьезно? Стали появляться минусы, ну так и что это ж не значит что эти минусы поставлены действительно справедливо, может тем кто поставил подсraть человеку охота. Если все головой будут стену ламать ты тоже будешь?

Comment: "Заголовок так себе и не отражает суть проблемы полностью." Почему не отображает? Мне лично все понятно, человек хочет чтобы вместо 1000 1к писало вместо 1.000.000 - 1М что тут не понятно.

Comment: @MadokaMagica старый заголовок был "Как убрать большие цифры в юнити?". Если не открыть вопрос, то лично мне сложно догадаться, о чём речь.

Comment: @MadokaMagica сами по себе пунктуационные ошибки - не очень  страшно. Но вот сочетание их с плохим заголовком и очень простым однострочным вопросом,который легче в гугле найти - вот причина минусов.

Comment: @Зонтик возможность загуглить грубо говоря имеется как раз благодаря тому что на подобные вопросы здесь уже имеются ответы. Но откуда им взяться, этим ответам, если мы будем рандомно каждого второго за такие вопросы банить?

Comment: @aepot дык уже есть такой вопрос, если бы не было, может реакция другая была бы :)
И кстати, он не однострочник и нормально оформлен.

Comment: @Зонтик на счет заголовка что пишешь плохой заголовок не понятно там. Я не знаю как другие, но я если и смотрю бывает редко но бывает, я смотрю в 1 очередь тег android, kotlin, java потому что я в этом компетентен. А с заголовка глупо требовать чтоб он все объяснил, надо заходить смотреть описание.

Comment: @Зонтик на момент написания этого поста на Мете, дубль ещё не был найден, а вопрос был открыт и было 3 голоса на закрытие с разными причинами. Но минусов с ходу накидали ни за что, поэтому я и пришёл на Мету поинтересоваться.

Comment: *"А вот метки расставлены хорошо"* - а вот метки расставлены ужасно, две из трёх меток лишние

Comment: `Заголовок так себе, Есть пунктуационные ошибки` по наличию которых можно было бы и догадаться, что сам он, без посторонней помощи(за которой кстати и пришел) **не может составить заголовок лучше имеющегося**, но нам видимо голова нужна чтоб шапку носить... `текст проверить` ц. тут ЕГЭ что ли?! ну что за кринж... хватит превращать SO в клуб анонимных граммарнаци. смысл ясен и ладно. `если поискать, обнаружим дубль`  чтоб что то искать, нужно составить **запрос понятный поисковому скрипту**, а тут и человеки не сильно то справились, и весь этот срач наглядное тому подтверждение...

Answer (score -3):

Это вообще частое явление, когда новичкам минусуют вопросы которые бы помогли только им, а не в целом сообществу, даже когда человек сам попытался разобраться но не получилось. Я понимаю, что зачастую вопросы типа "сделайте за меня домашку" раздражают, но агрессивно в комментариях обязательно кто-нибудь напишет даже на нормальный вопрос, или *намекает*, что новичок не прав, даже не отослав его на справку. Ну либо втихую минус потому что вопрос не понравился тем, что он не общий, а где просят решить конкретную проблему. Мне кажется нужна фича что на каждый минус обязательно надо описать причину, и если причина не "спам", то пускай минусующий скинет хоть ссылку на мету или просто справку, которая к слову в спорном состоянии, но это другая история.

UPD: "На каждый минус описать причину" - какое-нибудь выпадающее окошко с выбором "дубликат", "некачественный вопрос", "не по теме", "спам", где для дубликата требуется ссылка, для некачественного - ссылку на мету/справку/своими словами, не по теме - автоматически какой-нибудь Дух Сообщества писал что-нибудь в духе "ваш вопрос не связан с темой сайта" и закрывал его. Ну а для спама просто минус и всё, без объяснений.

Comment: мне понравилась мысль => "на каждый минус обязательно надо описать причину"

Comment: Всё это уже [обсуждалось](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277/176217) неоднократно.

Comment: Мне кажется, вы забываете для чего служат минусы, и многие почему-то их расценивают как, не знаю, оскорбление, призрение сообщества в свою сторону. На SO очень многое завязано на этих самых минусах, например, автоматическое удаление вопросов с минусами и без ответов через некоторое время. Ну вот возьмем тот вопрос, на который ссылаются тут, давайте подумаем, смысл какой в нем для SO? Человек попытался сам разобраться? Нет. Он несет пользу для SO? Нет. Значит минус на нем обоснован, верно? Думаю, да. И почему минусующий должен оставлять там "причину", если причина указана в описании "минуса"?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, подумайте, вы в самом деле считаете, что нужны люди для SO, а не  **SO для людей?** (т.е. интересы "коня сферического" для вас важнее, чем нужды конкретного человека)

Comment: @avp Любой инструмент, механизм, технология, создана для людей в первую очередь, НО, если у инструмента есть свои порядки, правила, то следует им следовать, а не пытаться использовать молоток для рубки дров. Поэтому да, для меня важней чистота и порядок ресурса, на котором я нахожусь, а не человек, который не в силах уделить 10 минут на базовые знания, и которому плевать на то место, в которое он пришел. Что касается минусов, то это тот-же инструмент, который нужно применять по назначению, например, этот ответ, я не согласен с ним, мое право поставить минус, верно? Для этого они и существуют.

Comment: Ох уж эта незыблемость правил... Доконает она в конце-концов когда-то хороший SO

Comment: @avp люди хотят, чтобы SO был качественной базой знаний — о боже какой ужас, да как так можно вообще, вопиюще неприемлемо

Comment: @andreymal, в данном случае люди хотят несбыточного (о подвешенной перед носом морковке и т.п. уже не буду)

Comment: @avp почему несбыточного? База же уже есть. Да, не такая большая, как на enSO, но всё равно есть.

Comment: @Зонтик, это не база а свалка. Для *базы знаний* необходима семантическая сеть между ее объектами и их иерархия. Неукротимая же борьба  с *метаметками* принципиально исключает возможность построения таких связей. / Еще раз. Реально, все что мы можем сделать *полезного* -- это практически помогать друг-другу, пытаясь отвечать на все (ну, кроме откровенного бреда) вопросы, а не борясь с ними, если они какой-то части отвечающих представляются неуместными

Comment: "Город насильников и убийц, какой смысл мне следовать правилам, приличиям, моральным ценностям, буду лучше как все, убивать и насиловать!" - вот примерно так я вижу текст выше. Мерзко такое даже видеть. Очень жаль, что ruSO сейчас на самоуправлении, такие "старожилы" только тащат ресурс на дно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ чем они тащат его на дно? Тем что отвечают на вопросы уровня "у меня не работает как написать код чтобы работало"?

Comment: @Aarnihauta Отношением в целом. SO управляется сообществом, как большинство решит, так с большой долью вероятности и будет. Ну а большинство, как я сказал ранее, считают SO форумом, "свалкой" а не тем, чем он является на самом деле.

Comment: "На каждый минус описать причину"  Вот вот а ты тыкнуть минус поставить и закрыть очень легко, вот этим и пользуются.

Comment: Вот например я задал вопрос "Почему вместо домена сайта открывается содержимое папки public_html?" мне уже натыкали минусов закрыть. Да может там страдает орфография, может не совсем точно сформулировал, но это вполне понятный вопрос, который я гуглил но не нашел ответа, ну на англ не смотрел но на русском нету, т.е. я веду к тому что этот вопрос будет полезен для сообщества, потому что похожая проблема может вылезти у новичка и он побежит писать вопрос потому что не сможет ничего нагуглить, а его опять возьмут закроют.

Comment: А потом у такого умника что закрытие тыкал такая же проблема вылезет и он полезет ее гуглить но у гугла не будет ответа потому что он и другие тыкали закрытие вопроса, по моему это даже забавно.